# FindOneAndUpdate MongoDB with Mongoose updating user's profile not working with email?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a REST API in Express JS and Mongo DB. I'm utilising the Mongoose package to interface with the database and am trying to implement a robust endpoint for allowing a user to update details about their account, for instance, their name.

My endpoint is setup, and I can send a request, however, it only seems to work if I don't pass through the email and password of the user I want to update (bearing in mind I need to check that the email they're changing it to doesn't already exist)

```js
router.patch('/update', verify, async (req, res) => {

  // validate incoming data
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body) 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

  // check if user already exists
  const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
  if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists')

  // hash password
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)

  // update user
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashPassword
  })
  
  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user.id }, user, { runValidators: true, useFindAndModify: false, new: true }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error')
      return res.status(400).send(error)
    }

    res.status(200).send(result)
  });

})
```

For a starters, I'm getting a returned `1` instead of an object, but earlier I was getting a Mongo DB error with the code of `66` for some reason...

What's going on here?

**UPDATE**

When sending my body to update a user, I get a response of: `{"operationTime":"6845592053464694785","ok":0,"code":66,"codeName":"ImmutableField","$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6845592053464694785","signature":{"hash":"+uHFhNsV5B60qR/Yhd2qg8Cd6jA=","keyId":"6843771360993345539"}},"name":"MongoError"}`, even though I've only edited the **name** out of the three fields

[image: postman setup]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get a field to make a query. You should know the _id or you should know the previous email or any unique field value.

You created a new user by the following code. But this created user also will have a unique id.

```js
const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashPassword
  })
```

But if you need to update, you should not create a new user.
A user never knows his id. So you should query your data by using any other field like email. You may be in need of this code

```js
await User.findByIdAndUpdate({email:req.body.existingemail},{
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashPassword
  })
```

So the code which will help you may be like this,

```js
router.patch('/update', verify, async (req, res) => {

    // validate incoming data
    const { error } = registerValidation(req.body) 
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
  
    // check if user already exists
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists')
  
    // hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
  
    // update user
    const user ={
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashPassword
    }
    //make sure you pass existingemail in postman
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ email:req.body.existingemail }, user, { runValidators: true, useFindAndModify: false, new: true }, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error')
        return res.status(400).send(error)
      }
  
      res.status(200).send(result)
    });
  
  })
```